# Time and speed - Theory of relativity - 'felt time'

Tags: relativity, time-dilation

Assuming time is relative according to the objects current speed, means that a clock within a space shuttle which has 30% of light speed is 'ticking' slower than a clock staying on planet earth just laying on the floor. Fine!

Since the 'ticking' is slower, due the changing position - would a person be able to have a longer conversation within this space shuttle than just laying next to the clock on the floor?

I don´t understand the connection between my intuitive feeling of time and the 'ticking' or regular moving of an clock or object.

Am I mixing up something? How is my feeling of time described within physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I mixing up something?

Yes. The clock is not ticking "slower" in any real sense. 
The clock is doing just fine, as is everyone in the space shuttle. Everything proceeds at a normal rate in the shuttle. It's just that people who observe the shuttle going by at 0.3c think that the clock is ticking slower. So yes, you are mixing up frames of reference.

> How is my feeling of time described within physics?

Physics does not deal with feelings.

Comment: *"Physics does not deal with feelings"* Physics loves you. Just open your heart to the love.

Comment: > "Physics does not deal with feelings" Physics loves you. Just open your heart to the love.  haha - no comment.

Comment: And yet, you commented

Comment: Touche! [Must have 15 chars!]